# complie error package com.qti.server does not exist

Tags: java, android, compilation

I am an Android developer. I want to use the class `ShutdownOem` in the

```
 file:/vendor/qcom/proprietary/oem-services/java/com/qti/server/power/ShutdownOem.java
```

And I used `com.qti.server.power` to import the class. But when compiling, there is error:

> error: package com.qti.server does not exist
>       import com.qti.server.power;

Do you know why?

The code of ShutdownOem.java is as below:

```
package com.qti.server.power;

import android.util.Log;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import dalvik.system.PathClassLoader;

public final class ShutdownOem {
    private static final String TAG = "QualcommShutdown";

    public void rebootOrShutdown(boolean reboot, String reason) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Qualcomm reboot/shutdown.");
        //Sub-system shutdown.
        if(SubSystemShutdown.shutdown() != 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to shutdown modem.");
        } else
            Log.i(TAG, "Modem shutdown successful.");
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying?

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
import com.qti.server.power.ShutdownOem;
```

Comment: try to insert  ShutdownOem.java in your package , hope it helps

Comment: sorry, could you give some more details? how to make it?

Comment: create a new class ShutdownOem.java in your project and copy the code , hope it helps